# Remove outliers in an image after applying treshold

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, outliers

Here`s the deal. I want to create a mask that visualizes all the changes between two images (GeoTiffs which are converted to 2D numpy arrays).

For that I simply subtract the pixel values and normalize the absolute value of the subtraction:

[image: Formula]

Since the result will be covered in noise, I use a treshold and remove all pixels with a value below a certain limit.

```py
def treshold(array, thresholdLimit):
      print("Treshold...")
      result = (array > thresholdLimit) * array
      return result
```

This works without a problem. Now comes the issue. When applying the treshold, outliers remain, which is not intended:

[image]

What is a good way to remove those outliers?
Sometimes the outliers are small chunks of pixels, like 5-6 pixels together, how could those be removed?

Additionally, the images I use are about 10000x10000 pixels.

I would appreciate all advice!

EDIT:

Both images are landsat satelite images, covering the exact same area.
The difference here is that one image shows cloud coverage and the other one is free of clouds.
The bright snakey line in the top right is part of a river that has been covered by a cloud. Since water bodies like the ocean or rivers are depicted black in those images, the difference between the bright cloud and the dark river results in the river showing a high degree of change.

I hope the following images make this clear:

Source tiffs : 
[image]
[image]

Subtraction result:
[image]

I also tried to smooth the result of the tresholding by using a median filter but the result was still covered in outliers:

```
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter

def filter(array, limit):
        print("Median-Filter...")
        filteredImg = np.array(median_filter(array, size=limit)).astype(np.float32)
        return filteredImg
```

Comment: Apply some smoothing before the threshold.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a little bit more background on how the two images you are substracting are related. Where does the expected difference you are trying to extract (-> your signal) come from and how does it differ from the noise? Looking at the example image it is not always obvious to me what is signal and what is noise (take for instance the bright snaky line in the upper right quadrant).

Comment: @FlorianDrawitsch that is a good point. I edited the question and hope that your question is cleared up.

Comment: Your first step should be to equalize the exposure in the two images. One is way brighter than the other. If you want to find differences by subtraction, you need to make the regions that have not changed identical. A simple multiplication with a constant will change the apparent exposure. You just need to find this constant to make the two images as similar as possible.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your response. Do you have an idea of how to find this constant?

Comment: If you have exposure settings associated to each image (these might be stored as metadata in the TIFF files) then it's just the ratio of these exposures. Otherwise you could set up a simple optimization problem. Least squares is always easy, but likely you'd get best results finding the value that minimizes the L1 error (i.e. minimize the absolute difference, rather than the square of differences). Of course, this assumes that you have a relatively large area not covered by clouds in both images, like your example here. It cannot work in a general case if clouds can cover everything you see.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Before proceeding please double check if the two images are 100% [registered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration). To check that you should overlay them using e.g. different color channels. Even minimal registration errors can render your task impossible
2. Smooth both input images slightly (before the subtraction). For that I would suggest you use [standard implementations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html). Play around with the filter parameters to find an acceptable compromise between smoothness (or reduction of graininess of source image 1) and resolution
3. Then try to match the image statistics by applying [histogram normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization), using the histogram of image 2 as a target for the histogram of image 1. For this you can also use e.g. the [OpenCV implementation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html)
4. Subtract the images
5. If you then still observe obvious noise, look at the histogram of the subtraction result and see if you can relate the noise to intensity outliers. If you can clearly separate signal and noise based on intensity, apply again a thresholding (informed by your histogram). Alternatively (or additionally), if the noise is structurally different from your signal (e.g. clustered), you could look into [morphological operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Opening) to remove it.